# Reverse engineer array dimensions from code indexing int arrays?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

So I'm trying to compute the values of P and Q in the following code with the assembly code given.

```
#define P ?                                       
#define Q ?                                       
int mat1[ P ][ Q ];                                   
int mat2[ Q ][ P ];                                   
void copy_element( int i, int j) {                
    mat1[ i ][ j ] = mat2[ j ][ i ];              
}
```

assembly:

````
copy_element:                                     
    movslq  %edi, %rdi           # variable i
    movslq  %esi, %rsi           # variable y
    leaq    (%rsi,%rsi,2), %rax               
    leaq    (%rsi,%rax,4), %rdx               
    leaq    (%rdx,%rdx), %rax                 
    addq    %rdi, %rax                        
    movl    mat2(,%rax,4), %ecx  # mat2[ Q ][ P ]
    leaq    0(,%rdi,8), %rdx                  
    subq    %rdi, %rdx                        
    leaq    0(,%rdx,4), %rax                  
    addq    %rax, %rsi                        
    movl    %ecx, mat1(,%rsi,4)  # mat1[ P ][ Q ]
    ret              ```
````

My friend is learning how to calculate the assembly code and unfortunately it was a RIP. he asked me to help but i didnt get far.

At this point, according to my calculations I should have:

```
%rdx = %rdi + (%rsi + %rax) + 4*((%rsi+%rax) + 2*(%rsi + %rax)).
```

Also I'm not quite sure how I would be able to get the array size from this.

Comment: You can get the second dimension from each of the arrays by reverse engineering the row size calculation. If you follow the calculation properly you will see `P=26` as the first `lea` does `3*j` then the second `4*3*j+j=13*j` and finally `2*13*j = 26*j`. You can work `Q` out in a similar fashion.

Comment: thank u for ur answer dude. so i guess Q = 15 ? just wanna make sure i got it right

Comment: No. `leaq    0(,%rdi,8), %rdx ` does `8*i` then the `subq` does `8*i-i=7*i` then the next `leaq` does `4*7*i=28*i` so that should mean `Q = 28`.